# Identify the tab and newline character with in a column of a UNIX file and remove it

Tags: shell, unix

[I have 4 columns of data. suppose if tab character present that row has > 4 columns of data . suppose new line character < 4 columns of data . how to identify and remove tab and new line character. click this link and see the input and output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQ1aB.png)

Comment: Format your data using the `{}` symbol in the editor toolbar. It is  barely readable. What is it got to with Oracle? Remove tags that are unrelated to your question.

Comment: Hard to understand. Is `{1}` a tab-character? Why is `11` in the input converted to `111` ? Is `{9}` a newline? Did ou try `tr -d '\t'` ?

Answer (score 0):

can you try this sed -e "s_/\n_/\t_g"

Comment: will it identify tab and new character or remove it from file

Comment: This site differs from a forum in that it values complete or somewhat definitive answers. Very short answers can be definitive but in this case, that might be better off as a comment. Consider editing your answer to explain how it applies.

Comment: I have 4 columns of data. suppose if tab character present that row has > 4 columns of data . suppose new line character < 4 columns of data . how to identify and remove tab and new line character. click this link and see the input and output image